# Java ME: how to unescaping XML &apos;

Tags: xml, java-me, escaping

I'm looking for how unescaping XML entities in a Java ME application, similar to `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml()` from `Apache Commons Lang 2.6`.

Other than cut-and-paste `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml()` sources in my project and recompiling with 1.3 compiler, is there a solution out there?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, after earned the Tumbleweed badge for this question, I answer it on my own.

The only solution I found was cut-and-paste `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml()` sources and recompiling for Java 1.3 compiler.